# How can I add text to a label from two different arrays in swift chosen at Random

Tags: arrays, swift, random, uikit

I have created a label with a frame on the screen which displays the chosen text. I also have two different arrays for the first and last name.

```swift
let nameArray = ["Jacob", "Lenny", "George", "Linda", "Arthur"]
let lastNameArray = ["Shelby", "Knight", "Luiz", "Hamilton", "Dobson"]
```

when I use `nameLabel.text = nameArray.randomElement()` it works fine, but I want it to display both a random first name and a random last name from the given arrays within the same label. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same thing but twice

```
nameLabel.text = "\(nameArray.randomElement()!) \(lastNameArray.randomElement()!)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [zip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) both array and then use random.

Here is solution

```
let nameArray = ["Jacob", "Lenny", "George", "Linda", "Arthur"]
let lastNameArray = ["Shelby", "Knight", "Luiz", "Hamilton", "Dobson"]
let combine = Array(zip(nameArray, lastNameArray))

let randomName = combine.randomElement() ?? ("", "")
nameLabel.text = randomName.0 + " " + randomName.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this way, `randomPerson` even creates (5) unique full names and starts over when all names are expended.

```
let firstNames = ["Jacob", "Lenny", "George", "Linda", "Arthur"]
let lastNames = ["Shelby", "Knight", "Luiz", "Hamilton", "Dobson"]

var tempFirstNames = [String]()
var tempLastNames = [String]()

func randomPerson() -> String {
    if tempLastNames.isEmpty {
        tempLastNames = lastNames
        tempFirstNames = firstNames
    }
    let firstName = tempFirstNames.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0..<tempFirstNames.count))
    let lastName = tempLastNames.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0..<tempLastNames.count))
    return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
}
```

And use it

```
nameLabel.text = randomPerson()
```